# Access Table calculated Field error: The expression couldn't be saved because its result type Binary or Null

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field, iif-function

I have TotalMarks field as ShortText because it could be a number or N/A. If [Math] value is N/A then TotalMarks is N/A otherwise sum of [Math]+[Physics]

```
IIf([Math]="N/A","N/A",CDbl([Math])+CDbl([Physics]))
```

[Math] and[Physics] are short text fields.

Comment: Your iif expression is correct.  If you are making a calculated field in a table(first don't do that), delete TotalMarks which started as ShortText and remake directly as a calculated field which should fix the issue.  Otherwise, it is probably a validation issue, check for something the iif statement can't handle like lowercase "n/a" in the math column or "N/A" in the physics column

Comment: Don't store calculated fields in table. Instead, use them in a query when needed wrapping nullable fields with the `Nz()` function to handle null values. `CDbl(Nz([Math],0))` will replace any null values with zero before converting to double to avoid errors.

Comment: If TotalMarks is a Calculated field, then it is not a ShortText type. CDbl() errors on Null.  Nz() is not available to table Calculated field. Calculate in query or textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Always store numbers as *number*. Thus:

- Change the data type of the fields to, say, *Double*
- Set *Default Value* for both fields to nothing (clear the property)
- Use *Null* for N/A
- Use this expression for *TotalMarks*: `=[Math]+[Physics]`
- Apply this *Format* to all three fields: `0.0000,,,"N/A"`. (Adjust count of decimals as needed)

(If outside the US, use this Format: `0,0000;;;"N/A"`)